# I've already updated to Windows 10; will I have to pay after the July 29 deadline?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

July 29th is the deadline for upgrading to Windows 10 free. I am currently on Windows 10. Will I have to pay anything to keep using it after that deadline passes?

Comment: If you want to upgrade to Windows 10 for free do it before the deadline, after the offer expires, you will be force to purchase a license to Windows 10 digitally.  If you are already running Windows 10, then you have a license to Windows 10, for the lifespan of the device it's on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you *already* have upgraded Windows to Windows 10, you have a lifetime license to use Windows 10 on your computer. The deadline only affects those who *haven't* upgraded yet.